# AJAX returns complete JSP file instead of return value

Tags: jquery, ajax

My AJAX code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url : "https://unpuckered-armament.000webhostapp.com/zyro/sandeep1.jsp",
    data : { search: 'test' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(json) {
        alert(json.title);
    }
});
```

and I have hosted my JSP file on 000webhostapp.com which is as follows:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("title", "TITLE_TEST");
    json.put("link", "LINK_TEST");
    out.print(json);
    out.flush();
%>
```

I have also tried:

```
 <%
        out.print("{\"name\":\"John\"}");
  %>
```

I have following problems:

1. Success function isn't called in AJAX.
2. When I checked in the Network of chrome, I saw that **I received entire file** with status = 200.
   Please advice.

[image]

---

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as I remember 000webhost only supports php, you will need a server that supports php in order to process the file, and not get the file contents. Your request is like if you were requesting a text file.